# Formula to calculate multiple dates in one cell

Tags: date

I have two columns, one with a date  ex. Nov 10.  In the second column bedside it I want to a formula to calculate a list of all dates at 1 week intervals for the month.  Currently I am using this formula =F10+7 but it only will generate Nov 17.  I would also a formula that will calculate the next week, and the following weeks for that month.  So the cell will look like Nov 10, 17, 24, 31.  Can this be done in one cell.
Thanks
Cybernurse

Answer (score 0):

If you're using LibreOffice Calc on Windows, give this formula a try:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", 0, TEXT(A1, "MMM DD"), TEXT(A1+7, "MMM DD"), TEXT(A1+14, "MMM DD"), TEXT(A1+21, "MMM DD"), TEXT(A1+28, "MMM DD"))
```

Sample output:

[image]

*Note: I would retain the month name in your cell results when future dates bleed into the next month, to avoid any confusion with the current month.*

If this formula does not work for you, then please clarify what application, app version, and OS you are targeting.